# Impact on Mongo query performance due to argument order?

Tags: mongodb, performance

General question about Mongo query performance and the order of query arguments.

We have a collection for storing "files" meta data which includes the file-name, and status of the file (integer code value). There will only be a small number of files in the collection with the same name (maybe a few dozen at most), however there can be thousands of files with the same status.

If there is a Mongo query structured something like this:

```
db.getCollection('files').find( { 
    '$and': [ 
        { 'name': 'someFileName.csv' },
        { 'status': { '$in': [ 12, 6 ] } } 
    ] 
})
```

...would it perform any differently then the same query formatted like this:

```
db.getCollection('files').find( { 
    '$and': [ 
        { 'status': { '$in': [ 12, 6 ] } }, 
        { 'name': 'someFileName.csv' }
    ] 
})
```

Which is to say: does the order of the $and clause arguments matter? Would scenario #1 perform better than scenario #2 since theoretically the file-name search would eliminate all but a few records? Or does Mongo operate in that manner under the covers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the order of the fields in a query doesn't matter.

Also, due to query fields being implicitly "anded", these would also be equivalent to:

```
db.getCollection('files').find( { 
    'status': { '$in': [ 12, 6 ] }, 
    'name': 'someFileName.csv'
})
```

and

```
db.getCollection('files').find( { 
    'name': 'someFileName.csv',
    'status': { '$in': [ 12, 6 ] }
})
```

They're all treated the same by the query analyzer when determining the optimal way to execute the query.